# swiftの構文[][]がわかりません。

Tags: swift

```
func getWeatherString(local:Area) -> String
{
   return ["晴れ","曇り","雨"][local.weather]
}
```

上記の `return ["晴れ","曇り","雨"][local.weather]` の構文が理解できません。
これはなんという仕組みなのですか？
ネットで調べようと思ってもキーワードがわかりません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return ["晴れ","曇り","雨"][local.weather]
```

この式を、複数の式に分解して書き直しましょう。そうすれば理解が早いかもしれません。

```
let number: Int = local.weather
let weathers: [String] = ["晴れ","曇り","雨"]
let theWeather: String = weathers[number]
return theWeather
```

配列から、添字を使って要素を取り出している処理ということがわかります。

Comment: ものすごく理解できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

["晴れ","曇り","雨"]は`Array`になります。
`local.weather`は`Integer`ではないでしょうか？
ですので、`local.weather`は0でしたら"晴れ”になります。２でしたら"雨"です。普通の構文ですがただ変数を使っていません。

Answer (score 2):

ただの配列で、[要素][添字]となっています。

```
println(["晴れ","曇り","雨"][0])
println(["晴れ","曇り","雨"][1])
println(["晴れ","曇り","雨"][2])
```

で

```
晴れ
曇り
雨
```

と出力されます。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。
２次元配列ということは、

let weather :[[String]] = [["晴れ","曇り","雨"]]

の２次元配列のインスタンスを生成して、
weather[0][0]は、["晴れ","曇り","雨"][0]　と 同義語になっているということですか？

なにかぴんときませんが。。。

Comment: 勘違いに気付きましたので、該当部分を修正しました。失礼しました。

Comment: @fuzzball 回答本文が更新されましたので、私のコメントを削除しました。